# Large File Upload in PHP Form Breaks Submission

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have a simple PHP form that emails some text data and a single file attachment. Everything is working fine, as long as the upload does not break any limits on the server, such as size or execution time, I believe. When the file breaks those limits, the browsers shows uploading 0% - 100% just fine, but instead of submitting the form, the page just refreshes, with no POST data being sent.

I don't have the option to increase any limits. I am working on a project where I cannot increase the limits for upload size or execution time via php.ini, .htaccess, or ini_set(). This is fine, and I am ok with the limits given to me by this particular client's hosting company.

However, I just need a user friendly way of submitting the form when a user tries to upload a large file that exceeds the limits, instead of the execution halting entirely and the page refreshing with no POST data. At this point, I can't even show any error to the user on submission, such as "File must be under 10MB", since the form never actually gets posted when the file is too large.

Please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: It should throw a `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` error that you can catch.

Comment: I assumed it was the size causing the issue, but I am seeing no errors in my log. What else could be causing it besides size? Memory? Execution time? Was hoping I would at least see some error, but I don't.

Comment: possibly a permissions issue? Do you have permission to upload to the directory you're uploading to?

Comment: @doliver Not sure. I am not saving the file, it is just being referenced from the tmp directory on upload. Also, it works fine with smaller files, so I don' think that is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, if your script is used to send your file as email attachment, it is true that your file should be under 10Mo because lots of mail servers will reject bigger emails.

For security reasons, you cannot access informations about a file from the browser. But as soon as the file is selected in a file field of a form, you can use HTML5 file API. [See this page for a complete presentation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Here is the portion of code you would need to handle file size before submission :

```
<input type="file" id="a_file" name="a_file" />
<script>
  function fileSelect(evt) {
    var file = evt.target.files[0];
    var size_mo = (file.size / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(3);

    if (size_mo >= 10)
    {
        alert('Your file is too big ('+size_mo+'Mo).');
        // eventually reset the form with window.your_form.reset() to avoid submit
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Your file is ready for upload ('+size_mo+'Mo)');
    }
  }
document.getElementById('a_file').addEventListener('change', fileSelect, false);
</script>
```

However this solution will only support up-to-date browsers and is not compatible with versions of Internet Explorer lower than 10.

There is no other solution using HTML or JS. If you want full support you will need Flash or Java (keep in mind that there are also computers with these technologies not installed).
So the best you can do is use the HTML5 code with browser detection and do not alarm the user if you can't read the file size and have the good behavior if HTML5 is supported.

Comment: This solution looks great, this particular client has a lot of ie7 - ie9 traffic though, which do not support the HTML5 File API. Any additional solutions for those browsers? Ref: http://caniuse.com/fileapi

Comment: @jackrugile There is no way to do this using HTML or JS with IE9 or lower support.
You can if you use a Java Applet asking for rights to read file system or using a Flash application.

Comment: @jackrugile I updated my answer. So it's now complete.